# linux raw ethernet socket bind to specific protocol

Tags: linux, sockets, ethernet

I'm writing code to send raw Ethernet frames between two Linux boxes. To test this I just want to get a simple client-send and server-receive.

I have the client correctly making packets (I can see them using a packet sniffer).

On the server side I initialize the socket like so:

```
fd = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(MY_ETH_PROTOCOL));
```

where `MY_ETH_PROTOCOL` is a 2 byte constant I use as an ethertype so I don't hear extraneous network traffic.

when I bind this socket to my interface I must pass it a protocol again in the socket_addr struct:
    `socket_address.sll_protocol = htons(MY_ETH_PROTOCOL);`
If I compile and run the code like this then it fails. My server does not see the packet. However if I change the code like so:
    `socket_address.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);`
The server then can see the packet sent from the client (as well as many other packets) so I have to do some checking of the packet to see that it matches `MY_ETH_PROTOCOL`.

But I don't want my server to hear traffic that isn't being sent on the specified protocol so this isn't a solution. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you paste the code where you set up your `socket_address`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have resolved the issue.

According to http://linuxreviews.org/dictionary/Ethernet/ referring to the 2 byte field following the MAC addresses:

> > "values of that field between 64 and 1522 indicated the use of the new 802.3 Ethernet format with a length field, while values of 1536 decimal (0600 hexadecimal) and greater indicated the use of the original DIX or Ethernet II frame format with an EtherType sub-protocol identifier."

so I have to make sure my ethertype is >= 0x0600.

According to http://standards.ieee.org/regauth/ethertype/eth.txt use of 0x88b5 and 0x88b6 is "available for public use for prototype and vendor-specific protocol development." So this is what I am going to use as an ethertype. I shouldn't need any further filtering as the kernel should make sure to only pick up ethernet frames with the right destination MAC address and using that protocol.

Comment: I have do as you said. But my client can not receive specified protocol packet. Can you paste your code? thank you! email: ycsunjane@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I've worked around this problem in the past by using a packet filter.

**Hand Waving** (untested pseudocode)

```
struct bpf_insn my_filter[] = {
    ...
}

s = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, htons(protocol));
struct sock_fprog pf;
pf.filter = my_filter;
pf.len = my_filter_len;
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ATTACH_FILTER, &pf, sizeof(pf));

sll.sll_family = PF_PACKET;
sll.sll_protocol = htons(protocol);
sll.sll_ifindex = if_nametoindex("eth0");

bind(s, &sll, sizeof(sll));
```

Error checking and **getting the packet filter right** is left as an exercise for the reader...

Depending on your application, an alternative that may be easier to get working is [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/).