# Ethernet Linux Control

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, ethernet, netfilter

I'm new on work with linux. I want capture the ethernet packets above the device drivers layer.

I know that all the packets pass through  the functions "dev_queue_xmit" to transmit the packet to the upper layer and the function "netfi_rx" for recieving the packet.

How can i "hook" this function to control the ethernet traffic?

what should i work with to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html) (a portable C/C++ library for network traffic capture). There is also an [example](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use raw sockets. http://aschauf.landshut.org/fh/linux/udp_vs_raw/ch01s03.html

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366812/linux-raw-ethernet-socket-bind-to-specific-protocol)