# Linux AF_PACKET sockets: Filtering for specific Ethertype protocol only works on loopback interface

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, ethernet, raw-sockets

I'm trying to write an application that is able to send/receive raw Ethernet frames on a specific network device. The point is that I want to be able to arbitrarily change the source MAC address and the [EtherType](https://standards-oui.ieee.org/ethertype/eth.txt).

I know that it is possible to access the raw layer 2 data by using `AF_PACKET` sockets in Linux. For a minimal example I've written a server application sending the raw frames and a client application receiving the frames, using [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20231113020140/http://www.microhowto.info/howto/capture_ethernet_frames_using_an_af_packet_socket_in_c.html) guide as a reference. My server looks like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/ether.h>

uint8_t src_mac[] = {0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66};

#define DEFAULT_IF  "eno1"
// #define DEFAULT_IF   "lo"

#define BUF_SIZ     1024

#define ETHER_TYPE  ETH_P_802_EX1   
// #define ETHER_TYPE   ETH_P_ALL   

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd;
    struct ifreq if_idx;
    struct ifreq if_mac;

    int tx_len = 0;
    char sendbuf[BUF_SIZ];

    struct ether_header *eh = (struct ether_header *) sendbuf;
    struct sockaddr_ll socket_address = {0};
    
    char ifName[IFNAMSIZ];
    strncpy(ifName, DEFAULT_IF, IFNAMSIZ-1);

    /* Open RAW socket to send on */
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETHER_TYPE))) == -1) {
        perror("socket");
    }

    /* Get the index of the interface to send on */
    memset(&if_idx, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
    strncpy(if_idx.ifr_name, ifName, IFNAMSIZ-1);
    if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &if_idx) < 0) {
        perror("SIOCGIFINDEX");
    }

    /* Get the MAC address of the interface to send on */
    memset(&if_mac, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
    strncpy(if_mac.ifr_name, ifName, IFNAMSIZ-1);
    if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &if_mac) < 0) {
        perror("SIOCGIFHWADDR");
    }

    /* Construct the Ethernet header */
    memset(sendbuf, 0, BUF_SIZ);
    memcpy(dst_mac, if_mac.ifr_ifru.ifru_hwaddr.sa_data, 6);
    memcpy(eh->ether_dhost, dst_mac, 6);
    memcpy(eh->ether_shost, src_mac, 6);

    /* Ethertype field */
    eh->ether_type = htons(ETHER_TYPE);
    tx_len += sizeof(struct ether_header);

    /* Set data required for sendto */
    socket_address.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    socket_address.sll_ifindex = if_idx.ifr_ifindex;
    socket_address.sll_halen = ETH_ALEN;
    socket_address.sll_protocol = htons(ETHER_TYPE);
    memcpy(socket_address.sll_addr, dst_mac, ETH_ALEN);

    /* Fill with dummy data */
    for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
        sendbuf[tx_len++] = i+65;
    }

    /* Send packet */
    if (sendto(sockfd, sendbuf, tx_len, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&socket_address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll)) < 0) {
        printf("Send failed\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I'm sending via the network interface `eno1` and since I'm developing a prototype for a layer 2 protocol my EtherType is `ETH_P_802_EX1` (0x88B5) for the moment. I pass the EtherType as an argument when creating the socket. I also use it when manually building the Ethernet frame and when creating the `sockaddr_ll` structure that is required as an argument for `sendto`. I tried sniffing the package on `eno1` with WireShark with `eth.type == 0x88b5` as a filter and the result is exactly what you would expect, the destination and source MAC addresses, the type 0x88B5, and the payload.

So far so good. However the problem arises when I try to receive the package with this specific type (0x88B5) in my client program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/ether.h>

const int BUFSIZE = 1024;

#define ETHER_TYPE  ETH_P_802_EX1   
// #define ETHER_TYPE   ETH_P_ALL

#define DEFAULT_IF  "eno1"
// #define DEFAULT_IF   "lo"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sockfd;
    char rcvbuf[BUFSIZE];

    struct ifreq if_idx;
    struct ifreq if_mac;
    struct sockaddr_ll socket_address = {0};

    char ifName[IFNAMSIZ];
    strcpy(ifName, DEFAULT_IF);

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETHER_TYPE))) == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Get the index of the interface to send on */
    memset(&if_idx, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
    strncpy(if_idx.ifr_name, ifName, IFNAMSIZ-1);
    if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &if_idx) < 0) {
        perror("SIOCGIFINDEX");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    struct sockaddr_ll addr = {0};
    addr.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    addr.sll_ifindex = if_idx.ifr_ifru.ifru_ivalue;
    addr.sll_protocol = htons(ETHER_TYPE);

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
        perror("bind");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    socklen_t addr_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll);

    puts("Listening...");
    while(1) {
        size_t n = recvfrom(sockfd, rcvbuf, BUFSIZE-1, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&socket_address, &addr_size);
        if(n < 0) {
            perror("Error receiving");
            return 0;
        }

        printf("Received %ld bytes\n", n);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

You can see that I, again, pass the EtherType as an argument when creating the socket. In theory this should filter all incoming packets for only the ones with the EtherType 0x88B5, thereby limiting the amount of data that must be passed from kernel- to userspace.
I also bind the socket to a specific device, and to the EtherType, which, according to [the man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html), can be used to receive only packages of the respective type.

Here comes the part that I don't understand: When I'm sending the packets vie the loopback interface `lo`, all received packets have the right EtherType, therefore confirming that the filter works and ensuring that I'm only receiving the packets I'm interested in.
When using interface `eno1`, however, I don't receive anything at all via this socket.
If I change the EtherType to `ETH_P_ALL`, which means no filter at all, I receive all incoming packets on this particular interface **including** the ones from the server program.

So here's my questions:

1. What's the exact difference between passing the EtherType when creating the socket and setting it after creation via `sll_protocol`?
2. What's the reason that the program works fine on the loopback interface and not on the physical one? Am I even using the functions correctly?
3. Is it even possible to achieve my desired behavior with this approach? If not, what's the better approach?

Comment: Are server and client on different systems? What [else] is on the LAN (e.g. router, etc.)? Is there anything in any firewall configuration that would be problematic?

Comment: Both programs run on the same system, which is a fresh Ubuntu 22.04, so no user defined firewalls that I know of. Are there any predefined filter rules that prevent network interfaces from sending Ethernet frames to themselves unless it's loopback?

Comment: Try to create a pair of virtual ethernet interfaces, e.g. veth0 and veth1. Send to veth0 and listen on veth1.

Comment: Still experimenting, but found this: [linux raw ethernet socket bind to specific protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3366812/5382650)

Comment: Running the programs in two separate network namespaces with virtual Ethernet devices, everything seems to work fine. The problem only appears to be present when using real physical hardware. I stumbled upon [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/comments/gygbs6/how_to_send_raw_bits_over_an_ethernet_interface/) Reddit thread which suggests that the driver or even the hardware itself may be at fault, since it's possible for it to drop faulty packages automatically. However wouldn't that clash with the fact that I'm able to receive the packages when using `ETH_P_ALL`?